# AWS Mobile Analytics Data not exported to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile-analytics

I have enabled export (S3 + Redshift) on my app, however I don't see data getting exported to S3.

The file jsonpaths/awseventexportjsonpaths.json has been created. I manually created the folder awsma/events since it wasn't there.

Checked the IAM role 'mobileanalytics-autoExportToS3', it points to the correct S3 bucket. The Redshift import routine seems to be functioning fine as well, I see following message in the log "data_export.etl: Skipping 2016/06/22...No Data exists for this date".

Is there any data size/time requirements for the S3 export to work, haven't come across any such restriction in the documentation. The export functionality was enabled atleast 12 hours ago.

Appreciate any help debugging the issue.

Comment: What is the permission on this directory that you created "events"?

Comment: Here's the policy: 
    `{"Statement": [
    {
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mobile-analytics-06-21-2016",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mobile-analytics-06-21-2016/*"
      ],
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}`

Comment: No not the policy does this "event" directory has ready permission on the instance.

Comment: Sorry, don't get you. That's the policy that the IAM role associated with the instance has it cascades down all the folders of 'mobile-analytics-06-21-2016'.

Comment: Check this "I manually created the folder awsma/events" so I wanted to know permission on the "Events" folder

Comment: In CloudWatch log I see the message "data_export.etl: There are no applications under folder: mobile-analytics-06-21-2016/awsma/events". So I believe the folder "events" is accessible via the IAM Role.